# regular expression for ipaddress and mac address

Tags: python, regex, ip-address, mac-address

can anyone suggest me the regular expression for ip address and mac address ?

i am using python & django

for example ,
http://[ipaddress]/SaveData/127.0.0.1/00-0C-F1-56-98-AD/

for mac address i tried following but didn't work

```
([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})

^([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})$
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
import re
s = "http://[ipaddress]/SaveData/127.0.0.1/00-0C-F1-56-98-AD/"

re.search(r'([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})', s, re.I).group()
'00-0C-F1-56-98-AD'

re.search(r'((2[0-5]|1[0-9]|[0-9])?[0-9]\.){3}((2[0-5]|1[0-9]|[0-9])?[0-9])', s, re.I).group()
'127.0.0.1'
```

Place this snippet in your django routing definitions file - `urls.py`

```
url(r'^SaveData/(?P<ip>((2[0-5]|1[0-9]|[0-9])?[0-9]\.){3}((2[0-5]|1[0-9]|[0-9])?[0-9]))/(?P<mac>([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2}))', SaveDataHandler.as_view()),
```

Comment: i have a following function so def SaveData(request,ipaddress):

and if i use your reg exp for mac address in urls.py
 ('^SaveData/([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})/',SaveData)

it is giving me SaveUserData() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given) error

Comment: You need to wrap it in another pair of parentheses: `('^SaveData/(?P<macaddr>([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2}))/', SaveData)`

Comment: i guess ?P<macaddr> represent the argument name of a function , but is it possible that we can do this without specifying the argument name in urls.py

Comment: I guess it is. In that case the url mapping would like this: `('^SaveData/(([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2}))/', SaveData)`.

Answer (score 3):

Your regular expression only contains two capturing groups (parentheses), so it isn't storing the entire address (the first group gets "overwritten").  Try these:

```
# store each octet into its own group
r"([\dA-F]{2})[-:]([\dA-F]{2})[-:]([\dA-F]{2})[-:]([\dA-F]{2})[-:]([\dA-F]{2})[-:]([\dA-F]{2})"
# store entire MAC address into a single group
r"([\dA-F]{2}(?:[-:][\dA-F]{2}){5})"
```

IP addresses get trickier because the ranges are binary but the representation is decimal.

```
# store each octet into its own group
r"(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5]))"
# store entire IP address into a single group
r"((?:\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5]))(?:\.(?:\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5]))){3})"
```

Comment: The best solution I found till now which is easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/^([0-2]?\d{0,2}\.){3}([0-2]?\d{0,2})$/` for IPv4 Address and `/^([\da-fA-F]{1,4}:){7}([\da-fA-F]{1,4})$/i` for IPv6 address.

You can combine these two as `/^((([0-2]?\d{0,2}\.){3}([0-2]?\d{0,2}))|(([\da-fA-F]{1,4}:){7}([\da-fA-F]{1,4})))$/i`. You can find a sample [here](http://regexr.com?2t9o0).

Ref: http://snipplr.com/view/49994/ipv4-regex/, http://snipplr.com/view/49993/ipv6-regex/

For Mac Address You can use `/^([0-9A-F]{2}[-:]){5}[0-9A-F]{2}$/i`. You can find a sample [here](http://regexr.com?2t9nt).

Comment: The IPv4 regex isn't correct as it will accept values, which are not valid IP addresses, e.g. 999.999.999.999.

Answer (score 0):

This is for MAC address:

```
([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})
```

Comment: well i don;t know what but if i use this reg exp then ultimately i am gtting AD only for 00-0C-F1-56-98-AD input

Comment: or try this one: ([a-fA-F0-9]{2}[:|\-]?){6}

Answer (score 0):

consider s=256.1.1.1
i'd like to make a little modification from Michal's answer:

```
def find_ip(s):
    part = '(2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[0-9])?[0-9]|25[0-5]'
    res =re.search(r'(^| )((%s)\.){3}(%s)' %(part,part), s,re.I )
    if res:
        return res.group().strip()
    else:
        return ''
```

notice '(^| )' means line start or space ahead, to avoid get '56.1.1.1' from '256.1.1.1'

Answer (score 0):

alright so this is what I use for IPV4

([0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}

tested with

127.0.0.1
255.255.255.255

and works for all

Answer (score 0):

I need to mac address validation and I have to accept mac address without separator and with colon and dash separators. So valid formats like this

- aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
- aa-bb-cc-dd-ee-ff
- aabbccddeeff

and mixed separators are invalid like this

- aa:bb-cc-dd:ee:ff

and **the validation code with regex like** this.

```
def validate_mac_address(mac_addr):
    pattern = '^(([0-9a-fA-F]{2}[:]){5}([0-9a-fA-F]{2})|([0-9a-fA-F]{2}[-]){5}([0-9a-fA-F]{2})|[0-9a-fA-F]{12})$'
    return not re.match(pattern, mac_addr) is None
```