# Change every IP and mac address as fast as possible (huge log file)

Tags: python, regex, replace

I've collected authentication procresses within a ~5GB Log-File.
Now I want to alter all parts of the data, which makes it possible to identify where the original data was comming from, because it will be used as training data for machine learning (and maybe published).

Since the logic whithin the data has to be preserved, I thought of changing the IP and MAC addresses with the modulo operator. But I don't know, how to (fast) replace all of them with python (re?).

My first attempt was to use re.search, sort the found IP in 4 parts and change every part with a different modulo operator. 
The problems occuring where:
- it's ugly
- it's slow
- only does it for the first match

Does anybody know a decent way to solve this problem ?

______EDIT_____

Example-logs:

RID: "700011"; RL: "1"; RG: "windows,authentication_failures,"; RC: "A Kerberos authentication ticket was requested: Failure."; USER: "(no user)"; SRCIP: "None"; HOSTNAME: "(boatyMcBoatface) 10.19.18.1->WinEvtLog"; LOCATION: "(boatyMcBoatface) 10.19.18.1->WinEvtLog"; EVENT: "[INIT]2018 Aug 01 01:59:40 WinEvtLog: Security: AUDIT_FAILURE(4768): Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing: (no user): no domain: boatyMcBoatface.haven.ssh: A Kerberos authentication ticket (TGT) was requested. Account Information:  Account Name:  BackupNow  Supplied Realm Name: haven.ssh  User ID:   S-1-0-0  Service Information:  Service Name:  krbtgt/haven.ssh  Service ID:  S-1-0-0  Network Information:  Client Address:  ::ffff:10.15.16.166  Client Port:  53680  Additional Information:  Ticket Options:  0x40810010  Result Code:  0x17  Ticket Encryption Type: 0xffffffff  Pre-Authentication Type: -  Certificate Information:  Certificate Issuer Name:    Certificate Serial Number:   Certificate Thumbprint:    Certificate information is only provided if a certificate was used for pre-authentication.  Pre-authentication types, ticket options, encryption types and result codes are defined in RFC 4120.[END]"; ' plugin_sid='700011' proto='6'  ctx='192222c3-2222-22222222-422222226754' src_host='' dst_host='' src_net='19111112c3-2222-22222222-422222226754' dst_net='333333a8-f526-1356-bbbe-005022285e074' username='BackupNow' userdata1='1' userdata2='windows,authentication_failures,' userdata3='A Kerberos authentication ticket was requested: Failure.' userdata4='krbtgt/haven.ssh' userdata5='0x17' userdata6='0xffffffff' userdata7='-' userdata9='haven.ssh' device='10.19.18.1'/>ost_dst='boatyMcBoatface' idm_mac_src='12:E4:B1:2B:B3:BB' idm_mac_dst='12:E4:B1:2B:B3:BB' device='10.19.19.23'/>

RID: "700003"; RL: "5"; RG: "windows,"; RC: "Windows Network Logon"; USER: "evservice"; SRCIP: "10.3.3.39"; HOSTNAME: "(boatyMcBoatface) 10.19.19.23->WinEvtLog"; LOCATION: "(boatyMcBoatface) 10.19.19.23->WinEvtLog"; EVENT: "[INIT]2018 Aug 01 01:59:37 WinEvtLog: Security: AUDIT_SUCCESS(4624): Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing: evservice: SSI-LOG: boatyMcBoatface.haven.ssh: An account was successfully logged on. Subject:  Security ID:  S-1-0-0  Account Name:  -  Account Domain:  -  Logon ID:  0x0  Logon Type:   3  New Logon:  Security ID:  S-1-5-21-88886292-694438636-1307214239-9687  Account Name:  myservice  Account Domain:  MY-LOG  Logon ID:  0x226aa299c6  Logon GUID:  {0354E718-498F-039C-83C2-725752D013BE}  Process Information:  Process ID:  0x0  Process Name:  -  Network Information:  Workstation Name:   Source Network Address: 10.3.3.39  Source Port:  61266  Detailed Authentication Information:  Logon Process:  Kerberos  Authentication Package: Kerberos  Transited Services: -  Package Name (NTLM only): -  Key Length:  0  This event is generated when a logon session is created. It is generated on the computer that was accessed. [END]"; ' plugin_sid='700003' proto='6'  ctx='584a8883-a333-22a6-adde-000000876224' src_host='' dst_host='aaaaaaa-2ebf-e2ea-eee-e053079999ed' src_net='555555-f226-11e6-bbbb-005056876974' dst_net='666666de-2be4-8242-1d75-45b6aaaaaaaa' username='myservice' userdata1='5' userdata2='windows,' userdata3='Windows Network Logon' userdata4='4624' userdata5='3' userdata6='MY-LOG' userdata7='0x226cb22322' userdata8='-' idm_host_dst='boatyMcBoatface' idm_mac_dst='A1:15:14:AB:1C:1D' device='10.19.19.23'/>

RID: "700014"; RL: "1"; RG: "windows,authentication_failures,"; RC: "Kerberos user pre-authentication failed."; USER: "(no user)"; SRCIP: "None"; HOSTNAME: "(my-dc02) 22.22.65.6->WinEvtLog"; LOCATION: "(my-dc02) 22.22.65.6->WinEvtLog"; EVENT: "[INIT]2018 Aug 01 09:04:50 WinEvtLog: Security: AUDIT_FAILURE(4771): Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing: (no user): no domain: my-dc02.my.ssh: Kerberos pre-authentication failed. Account Information:  Security ID:  S-1-5-21-1993962763-602162358-1801674531-2146  Account Name:  sys-dobackup  Service Information:  Service Name:  krbtgt/gb  Network Information:  Client Address:  ::ffff:22.22.1.1  Client Port:  61391  Additional Information:  Ticket Options:  0x40810010  Failure Code:  0x18  Pre-Authentication Type: 2  Certificate Information:  Certificate Issuer Name:    Certificate Serial Number:    Certificate Thumbprint:    Certificate information is only provided if a certificate was used for pre-authentication.  Pre-authentication types, ticket options and failure codes are defined in RFC 4120.  If the ticket was malformed or damaged during transit and could not be decrypted, then many fields in this event might not be present.[END]"; ' plugin_sid='700014' proto='6'  ctx='aaaaaaa-e2cf-12a9-9c1f-288888a5c27' src_host='aaaaaa3-ff38-22e6-b718-01544442f94' dst_host='55555ec3-ff20-5515-8059-0011111a2b4' src_net='a6d1111d-7111-811d-f35-f4ea131269107' dst_net='44449bea-960c-4446-6f444-d4444f159b8' username='sys-dobackup' userdata1='1' userdata2='windows,authentication_failures,' userdata3='Kerberos user pre-authentication failed.' userdata4='4771' userdata5='2' userdata6='krbtgt/gb' userdata7='0x18' idm_host_src='do-dc01' idm_host_dst='my-dc02' idm_mac_src='11:30:22:37:33:63' idm_mac_dst='22:21:56:44:14:21' device='22.22.65.6'/>

____EDIT_2___

Example:

_____Before____

```
1 date time src_ip=192.168.1.1 dst_ip=192.168.1.2 msg
2 date time src_ip=192.168.1.1 dst_ip=192.168.1.3 msg
3 date time src_ip=192.168.1.9 dst_ip=192.168.1.2 msg
```

_____After_____

```
1 date time src_ip=1.168.1.2 dst_ip=1.168.1.3 msg
2 date time src_ip=1.168.1.2 dst_ip=1.168.1.4 msg
3 date time src_ip=1.168.1.10 dst_ip=1.168.1.3 msg
```

My_garbage_code:

```
import re
file = "C:\Users\Hank\Desktop\Huge.log"
file2 = "C:\Users\Hank\Desktop\Huge2.log"

searchstring = "some_regex_magic"
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:            
        result = re.findall(searchstring, line)

        if result:
            ip = old_ip+anonymize_em_all
            #No Idea, how to add them back into the string at the correct postion
            #replace  them directly maybe, without writing a new file ?
            res2 ="+ip+\n"
            with open(file2,"a") as myfile:
            myfile.write(res2)
            myfile.close()
```

best regards

Comment: how are you mapping mac adresses to IP adresses? do you have a file or dataset you can use, or do you need to do a lookup for each IP?  could you share a couple of lines of log file as an example?

Comment: re.findall() will return a list of all the occurrences of your regex in a string. it returns a match object you can then iterate over. I would also suggest you look at the regex module https://pypi.org/project/regex, which is more powerful than re.

Comment: I wasn't going to map IP to MAC addresses , if I alter all MAC and IP addresses the same way, the correlation is preserved. 

EDIT:
thanks for you help - I will manualy alter a few lines and post them.

Comment: If you want to change them all in the same way, why don't you use the IP as a string and just do an MD5 or SHA256 on it? Also, the modulo operation is reversible, I wouldn't use that. As for the "matching only the first one", you'll need to post your code for anyone to determine where your problem is.

Comment: "Matching the first one" was because I used re.search - splitting the IP in 4 parts and editing every part with modulo, putting em back together and replacing  them with the old IP.  I can use your way to change the Username - but I think md5 over the whole ip would change it too much (wouldn't be recognized as IP anmyore).

Comment: "I wasn't going to map IP to MAC addresses , if I alter all MAC and IP addresses the same way, the correlation is preserved. EDIT: thanks for you help - I will manualy alter a few lines and post them." - your before and after code is the same. I am confused.  *** if you simply need to anonymize the ip adress, use re.sub in the way that segFaulter has shown below.

Comment: Yes, I want to anonymize the data, but I can't simply replace every IP and MAC with the same string.  I want to preserve the logical information of the data - for example that Machine27a connected to Machine12c at some point - but all this with anonymized IP- and MAC-Addresses.

Comment: I am going to make a "list" of regex.matches with findall - iterate through and hash the matches with argon2 - thanks for all the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

try using the below code, its rough around the edges but doing the replacement.

```
import re

input=["1 date time src_ip=192.168.1.1 dst_ip=192.168.1.2 msg",
"2 date time src_ip=192.168.1.1 dst_ip=192.168.1.3 msg",
"3 date time src_ip=192.168.1.9 dst_ip=192.168.1.2 msg"]

for line in input:
    print re.sub("\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}","x.x.x.x",line)
```

Sample output:

```
1 date time src_ip=x.x.x.x dst_ip=x.x.x.x msg
2 date time src_ip=x.x.x.x dst_ip=x.x.x.x msg
3 date time src_ip=x.x.x.x dst_ip=x.x.x.x msg
```

Hope this helps! cheers!

Comment: as an extra, there are standard regex expressions to check an IP adress and a mac adress. e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5287509/5464355