# How to verify that user input is in the correct format in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a script in python and I need to verify that the user input is in the correct format, like 000.000 or 00.0 or any other combination of the first 2 segments of an IP (0 can be any digit).

I have tried using the metacharacter "|" and the special sequence "\d" from the re module to make all the possible combinations but now even if I type something like 14576.2345 it is marked as correct user input.

```
import re

ip_class = input("Enter ip class: ")

def ip_range(ip_start):
    pattern= r"(\d+\d+\d+.+\d+\d+\d|\d+\d+.+\d+\d|\d+.+\d|\d+\d+\d+.+\d+\d|\d+\d+\d+.+\d|\d+\d+.+\d+\d+\d|\d+.+\d+\d+\d|\d+\d+.+\d|\d+.+\d+\d)"
    match = re.match(pattern, ip_start)
    if match:
        print ("it works")
    else:
        print ("it doesnt work")

ip_range(ip_class)
```

I expect that if I type somthing that can't be the first 2 segments of an ip like 234534.1345 it would say "It doesn't work" but it says "it works"
It says it works to every number that is at least 3 digits long even without the period.

Comment: `+` means one or more. You need just `\d` instead of all `\d+`, I guess and `.` is not dot, it's a single character (you have to escape them).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regular expression for ipaddress and mac address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287381/regular-expression-for-ipaddress-and-mac-address)

Comment: The re documentation includes how to match ranges of characters (e.g. one-to-three digits) and literal dots.

Comment: Consider using a regex validation/test service such as https://regex101.com .This gives you ample information why a regex does not behave as expected.

Comment: Also (for python 3.4+ ) you can use the `ipaddress` library https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html in order to handle various tasks related to IP addresses.

Comment: Thanks Austin, it works now. And thanks MisterMiyagi for the regex validation, I will use it in the future.

Answer (score 3):

```
import socket
somestr = '123.0xe0f'
try:
    addr = socket.inet_aton(somestr)
except OSError as e:
    raise    # String was not an inet address
```

This is a case where it's far easier to check for failure than guess. There may be quite a few more valid formats than you expect. Also, `.` is a wildcard in regular expressions.

You could also use `socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET, somestr)` if you want specifically the quad-dotted notation. That is also expressible as an overly complex regular expression.

Edit: My sloppy reading somehow skipped over "first 2 segments". I suppose one way to do that is to append `".0.0"` for this check, though that still allows either one or two segments.

Regular expressions are not ideal for bound checking numbers. For instance, a non-zero-prefixed decimal number from 0 to 255 might be `\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]`. Now consider how clear it will be to the next reader of the code not only what a regular expression containing at least two such groups is intended to check, but also that it does it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here it goes.

```
import re

ip_class = input("Enter ip class: ")

def ip_range(ip_start):
    pattern= r"(\d{3}.\d{3})"
    match = re.match(pattern, ip_start)
    if match:
        a = ip_class.split(".")

        for b in a:
            if int(b) not in range(0,256):
                print ("it doesnt work")
                return
        print ("it works")
    else:
        print ("it doesnt work")

ip_range(ip_class)
```

Comment: No. it doesn't.